# Force and Restrain on same Regex

Tags: html, regex, passwords

I'm trying to set a password input that will force at least one of each lowercase, uppercase, and numbers, but at the same time refuse any other input like special characters. so far im able to force one of each but haven't been able to deny special characters..
Thank You

```
pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{5,25}"
```

Comment: Disallowing all non-alphanumeric characters usually isn't a good idea concerning passwords, it reduces pasword strength and may cause issues for users using a password manager.

Comment: i understand about the security risks.. this is just a school proyect, and more just for my own curiosity as to how to restrain and force on the same regex.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the consuming `.` with `[a-zA-Z0-9]` character class, or whatever chars/ranges you allow in your regex:

```
pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,25}"
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The reason is that `.` matches any character (other than line break chars).

Note: the length limit works here because HTML5 `pattern` regex is anchored by default.

Comment: Thank You.. this worked as expected.. and helped me understand i was only forcing and NOT restraining..